# Why is using state as a string in my calendar component not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to mark a date on my calendar, this works:

```
<Calendar 
  markedDates={{
  '2020-07-22': {selected: true, marked: false, selectedColor: '#ff7f00'},}}
   onDayPress={(day) => this.manageGroups(day)}
/>
```

However when I try to change the date from a hard coded one to a state, it does not work. Here is how I am doing it.

```
<Calendar 
      markedDates={{
      '${this.state.currentDate}%': {selected: true, marked: false, selectedColor: '#ff7f00'},}}
       onDayPress={(day) => this.manageGroups(day)}
    />
```

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: For one thing that's not a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), it's just a regular string.

Comment: `[\`${this.state.currentDate}%\`]: {}` you need backticks to make it template literal and square brackets to use computed property name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep, thats what I thought. But there is a percent symbol in there. :) So I kept it as literal assuming it means something.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

```
<Calendar 
  markedDates={{
  `${this.state.currentDate}`: {selected: true, marked: false, selectedColor: '#ff7f00'},}}
   onDayPress={(day) => this.manageGroups(day)}
/>
```